# Customization for creating implementations of a base type

Tags: c#, autofixture

So I have the following types:

```cs
public abstract class Base
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public abstract int Value { get; set; }
}

public class BaseImplA : Base
{
    public override int Value { get; set; }
}

public class BaseImplB : Base
{
    public override int Value
    {
        get { return 1; }
        set { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
}
```

I want AutoFixture to alternate creating BaseImplA and BaseImplB when Base is requested.

```cs
var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new TestCustomization());
var b1 = fixture.Create<Base>();
var b2 = fixture.Create<Base>();
```

The issue is BaseImplB throws a NotImplementedException from the Value property setter. So I created the following customization:

```cs
public class TestCustomization : ICustomization
{
    private bool _flag;
    private IFixture _fixture;

    public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
    {
        _fixture = fixture;

        fixture.Customize<BaseImplB>(composer =>
        {
            return composer.Without(x => x.Value);
        });

        fixture.Customize<Base>(composer =>
        {
            return composer.FromFactory(CreateBase);
        });
    }

    private Base CreateBase()
    {
        _flag = !_flag;

        if (_flag)
        {
            return _fixture.Create<BaseImplA>();
        }

        return _fixture.Create<BaseImplB>();
    }
}
```

But what's happening is that the Value is not being set for BaseImplA or BaseImplB. Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong?

Comment: You need to customize the `Fixture` instance as: `fixture.Customize(new TestCustomization());` After doing this, no exception should be thrown.

Comment: "Value is not being set for BaseImplA or BaseImplB"... You don't want it to set `Value` for `BaseImplB`, do you? Am I guessing correctly that you also want the `Text` property to be populated?

Comment: @NikosBaxevanis I am doing the fixture.Customize(...). Sorry I left that part out from my sample.

Comment: @MarkSeemann That's right, I don't want Value to be set in BaseImplB but I want Text to be populated. Is that possible?

Comment: @MarkSeemann I've created a [github repo](https://github.com/perezgb/AutoFixtureSandbox) with the code and some tests that show what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I was about to answer this, but I may have discovered a bug in AutoFixture. I'm currently travelling, so it may take a day or two, but I'll get back to you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With AutoFixture 3.18.5+, this isn't too difficult to do. There's at least two different issues in play here:

**Dealing with BaseImplB**

The `BaseImplB` class needs special treatment, which is quite easy to deal with. You only need to instruct AutoFixture to ignore the `Value` property:

```cs
public class BCustomization : ICustomization
{
    public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
    {
        fixture.Customize<BaseImplB>(c => c.Without(x => x.Value));
    }
}
```

This omits the `Value` property, but otherwise creates instances of `BaseImplB` as usual, including filling out any other writable properties, such as the `Text` property.

**Alternating between different implementation**

In order to alternate between `BaseImplA` and `BaseImplB`, you can write a Customization like this:

```cs
public class AlternatingCustomization : ICustomization
{
    public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
    {
        fixture.Customizations.Add(new AlternatingBuilder());
    }

    private class AlternatingBuilder : ISpecimenBuilder
    {
        private bool createB;

        public object Create(object request, ISpecimenContext context)
        {
            var t = request as Type;
            if (t == null || t != typeof(Base))
                return new NoSpecimen(request);

            if (this.createB)
            {
                this.createB = false;
                return context.Resolve(typeof(BaseImplB));
            }

            this.createB = true;
            return context.Resolve(typeof(BaseImplA));
        }
    }
}
```

It simply deals with requests for `Base`, and relays alternating requests for `BaseImplA` and `BaseImplB` to the `context`.

**Packaging**

You can package up both Customizations (and others, if you have them) in a Composite, like this:

```cs
public class BaseCustomization : CompositeCustomization
{
    public BaseCustomization()
        : base(
            new BCustomization(),
            new AlternatingCustomization())
    {
    }
}
```

This will enable you to request `BaseImplA`, `BaseImplB`, and `Base`, as you need them; the following tests demonstrate this:

```cs
[Fact]
public void CreateImplA()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new BaseCustomization());

    var actual = fixture.Create<BaseImplA>();

    Assert.NotEqual(default(string), actual.Text);
    Assert.NotEqual(default(int), actual.Value);
}

[Fact]
public void CreateImplB()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new BaseCustomization());

    var actual = fixture.Create<BaseImplB>();

    Assert.NotEqual(default(string), actual.Text);
    Assert.Equal(1, actual.Value);
}

[Fact]
public void CreateBase()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new BaseCustomization());

    var actual = fixture.CreateMany<Base>(4).ToArray();

    Assert.IsAssignableFrom<BaseImplA>(actual[0]);
    Assert.NotEqual(default(string), actual[0].Text);
    Assert.NotEqual(default(int), actual[0].Value);

    Assert.IsAssignableFrom<BaseImplB>(actual[1]);
    Assert.NotEqual(default(string), actual[1].Text);
    Assert.Equal(1, actual[1].Value);

    Assert.IsAssignableFrom<BaseImplA>(actual[2]);
    Assert.NotEqual(default(string), actual[2].Text);
    Assert.NotEqual(default(int), actual[2].Value);

    Assert.IsAssignableFrom<BaseImplB>(actual[3]);
    Assert.NotEqual(default(string), actual[3].Text);
    Assert.Equal(1, actual[3].Value);
}
```

**A note on versioning**

This question surfaced a bug in AutoFixture, so this answer will not work unmodified in versions of AutoFixture prior to AutoFixture 3.18.5.

**A note on design**

AutoFixture was originally build as a tool for Test-Driven Development (TDD), and TDD is all about feedback. In the spirit of [GOOS](http://amzn.to/VI81bP), you should listen to your tests. If the tests are hard to write, you should consider your API design. AutoFixture tends to amplify that sort of feedback, and that also seems to be the case here.

As given in the OP, the design violates the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), so you should consider an alternative design where this is not the case. Such an alternative design is also likely to make the AutoFixture setup simpler, and easier to maintain.

Comment: Awesome @mark. And I appreciate the feedback on the design as well. I'll certainly take it into consideration and try to find an alternative. I agree 100% with you, when my tests start to get too convoluted it's a pretty good sign that my implementation my be less than ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Mark Seemann provided an excellent response. You can build a reusable rotating specimen builder for your abstract base types like this:

```
public class RotatingSpecimenBuilder<T> : ISpecimenBuilder
{
    protected const int Seed = 812039;
    protected readonly static Random Random = new Random(Seed);

    private static readonly List<Type> s_allTypes = new List<Type>();
    private readonly List<Type> m_derivedTypes = new List<Type>();
    private readonly Type m_baseType = null;

    static RotatingSpecimenBuilder()
    {
        s_allTypes.AddRange(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes()));
    }

    public RotatingSpecimenBuilder()
    {
        m_baseType = typeof(T);
        m_derivedTypes.AddRange(s_allTypes.Where(x => x != m_baseType && m_baseType.IsAssignableFrom(x)));
    }

    public object Create(object request, ISpecimenContext context)
    {
        var t = request as Type;
        if (t == null || t != m_baseType || m_derivedTypes.Count == 0)
        {
            return new NoSpecimen(request);
        }

        var derivedType = m_derivedTypes[Random.Next(0, m_derivedTypes.Count - 1)];
        return context.Resolve(derivedType);
    }
}
```

Then register this specimen builder as your fixture customization for each base type like this:

`var fixture = new Fixture.Customizations.Add(new RotatingSpecimenBuilder<YourBaseType>());`